# Python os.path.isfile() return false scenario

Tags: python-2.7, filesystems

I am trying to find situations when `os.path.isfile()` returns false. I have the following code which checks if the content is not a file (should have used `isdir()`) and does structured zip.

```
for fpath in glob(os.path.join(local_dir, glob_wildcard)):
    dirpath, filename = os.path.split(fpath)
    try:
        if not os.path.isfile(fpath):
            //code for structured zipping and move
        else:
            //move the file as is
```

This was working fine until now but recently found some of the files are getting zipped, than getting moved. One cause was, I have found another instance running at the same time which stole the file and `isfile()` for this instance returned false. So, it created an empty zip file.

Are there any other scenarios when it will return false? like file getting created or copied etc.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `isfile()` returns true if the file exists *in the microsecond when this check runs*. Anything that happens a microsecond before or after that is not relevant. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: Corollary - don't rely on `isfile()`. You must always assume that the result of `isfile()` and similar functions is out of date on the next line of code. The correct way to work with this filesstem is extremely straight-forward: Do the operation you want to do (open, move, copy, ...) without any prior checks (!). Do it in a `try` block and catch the exception if the operation fails.

Comment: The aim is to move content of the dir, if it is a file, move as is, but if it is directory do the structured zip and move the zip remove the directory etc. thats why the check. Python definition for `isfile()` is returns true for regular file. I am trying to find out, when a file is not a regular file.

Comment: You say *"another instance running at the same time which stole the file"*, so I have no idea why you are surprised. A file can be there right now and gone in the next millisecond, there is no guarantee whatsoever that the return value of `isfile()` is worth anything at all. However, `isfile()` will **never** return `true` when the target path does not point to a file, I just don't understand why you are fixed on this particular question.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for your replies, I know my question is not clear. But the issue I am trying to dig up is like that. I dont have any logs, but can see empty zip files created. To confirm that the code has created the zip file and not some body has dropped the zip file, I am trying to find when all `isfile()` returns false. One is that another instance stealing the file, which I think is the case here. But wanted to rule out other possibilities. That's why I am worried, if there any chance that `isfile()` returns False other than the above situation. The files are dropped by another system.

Comment: All `isfile()` does is call the respective native API function of the underlying operating system. And the operating system API is not confused about how the filesystem works. It returns correct information about the given path.